How to Modify Invoice Total Calculation in Vtiger CRM?
I'm currently working with Vtiger CRM, and I need to modify the way the total for invoices is calculated. Specifically, I want to change the total calculation logic to include some custom business rules.
I've located the Invoice class in modules/Invoice/Invoice.php but i didnt know where to modify

If the calculations are not too complicated, you will probably be able to do it by modifying the templates.
This is the template used to view the quotes/so/po/invoices:
layouts/v7/modules/Inventory/LineItemsDetail.tpl

And this is the template used to edit the quotes/so/po/invoices:
layouts/v7/modules/Inventory/partials/LineItemsContent.tpl


theres no javascript script or php that i can modify ?

Maybe you can create a workflow that runs a custom function when an invoice is modified. Or create an event handler beforesave or aftersave the invoice... But -even if it sounds a bit weird- as far as i know, vtiger itself does the calculations on the template.

Create an "After Save" eventhandler. There you can create a quey that modifies the vtiger_invoice table. That way, you don't need to modify vtiger's core files (which is good for updates).
You can learn more about eventhandlers here: https://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/vtlib/module-event.html
